# How do I change the notification area icon size in UbuntuMATE 17.04?

Tags: icons, notification, mate, ubuntu-mate

When I change the height of the panel bar, the notification area icons (network, bluetooth, sound, remmina) scale with it.

Is there a way to scale the icons independently of the panel height? Or add padding around the icons?

The various icon size adjustments in Mate Tweak only seem to apply to certain icons like the application menu, weather, etc.